# Which elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ have multiplicative inverses?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, inverse

> Which elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ have multiplicative inverses?
>   What's the multiplicative inverse of $7$ and $11$?

I'm currently practicing for a small test tomorrow and I'd like to know if I did this right?

The following elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ have multiplicative inverses (because they are relatively prime to $12$):

$$\left\{5;7;11\right\}$$

"What's the multiplicative inverse of $7$?"

We have to find an element, if we multiply it with $7$ we get $1$ as result. It's $\frac{1}{7}$...?

Comment: Hint: Don't miss the identity out of that group. Second hint: you'll find the inverses in the same group of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that $5,7,11$ are invertible mod $12$, but you're missing $1$. It turns out that $5,7$, and $11$ are all their own inverses mod $12$. This can be verified by hand, or using the Chinese remainder theorem:
$$ (\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\simeq C_2\times C_2 $$
where $C_2$ is a cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: Hmm I don't quite understand: "You are correct that $5,7,11$ are invertible mod $7$. The question "What's the multiplicative inverse of $7$?" was a separate one. So what's its multiplicative inverse now?

Comment: Oh, I meant mod $12$, sorry. As I said in the next sentence, $5,7,11$ are their own inverses mod $12$. For instance, $7^2=49\equiv 1$ (mod $12$).

Answer (score 0):

Since $$-7(5)+12(3)=1$$

$$7(-5) \equiv 1 \mod 12$$

$$7(7) \equiv 1 \mod 12$$